# Select returning a collection of true/false values, not a list of objects matching criteria

Tags: c#, .net, linq

```
var data = ...; //IList<MyClass>
var subset = data.Select(x => x.Name != null);
```

I was expecting this to return all the objects where `Name` is not null... instead I get a list of bool values true/false indicating whether that item in the original list matched the test.

Is this normal?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is [Where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.100).aspx) extension:

```
var subset = data.Where(x => x.Name != null);
```

Comment: Ah... I think I must have seen a very dodgy example somewhere and copied it.